# Duplicate the parent tag with its child tags in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I want to duplicate the parent tag with its children depend on the number of items of the user input in python.

This is the xml:

```
<Invoice>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:Item>
        <cbc:Name>Item A</cbc:Name>
        <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
    </cac:Item>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Is there any idea where I can duplicate the **item** **tag** depends on the user input? so if there is a two items entered the xml should be:

```
<Invoice>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Item A</cbc:Name>
            <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
            <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Item B</cbc:Name>
            <cbc:Percent>50</cbc:Percent>
            <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: What have you tried, what is your code or problem?

Comment: A basic issue is that an XML parser will interpret `cac`and `cbc` as namespace prefixes that are not properly declared. Your XML is not well-formed because of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **valid XML** similar like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:cac="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:cbc="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">&gt; 
<Invoice>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>Item A</cbc:Name>
      <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
      <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
    </cac:Item>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice></root>
```

You can **`extend()`** your XML. Do this in a `while` or `for` loop, how often you like or it's necessary. After that you can change the  values if needed:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

file_path = "Kaput.xml" # shared XML in the question is invalid / incomplete
tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()

# Assumtion for explanation only
ET.register_namespace('cac', "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/") # Must be adjusted according your root namespace
ET.register_namespace('cbc', "https://www.w3schools.com/furniture") # Must be adjusted according your root namespace

print("### START ###")
ET.dump(root)
print("### ##### ###")

for elem in root:
    branch = copy.deepcopy(elem)
    # Change tag values of the copy
    for child in branch.iter():
        print(child.tag)
        if child.tag == "{https://www.w3schools.com/furniture}Name":
            child.text = 'Item B'
        if child.tag == "{https://www.w3schools.com/furniture}Percent":
            child.text = '50'
            
# Insert the changed copy into the tree
root.find(".//{*}Invoice").extend(branch)  

print()
print("### START + ###")
ET.dump(root)
print("### ##### ###")

# Write the changed xml to file
tree.write("Modified_XML.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root xmlns:cac="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:cbc="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">&gt; 
<Invoice>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>Item A</cbc:Name>
      <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
      <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
    </cac:Item>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>Item B</cbc:Name>
      <cbc:Percent>50</cbc:Percent>
      <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
    </cac:Item>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice></root>
```